# SplitViewController PopOver from a Button instead of barButton Item

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I am trying to add a popOver controller in Portrait but I have ran into a problem because I am using a navigation controller in the detail view. The problem is I have a back button I need many times but when I rotate to portrait the popOver Bar item removes it. I am trying to add a Button below the navigation bar to open the master view but when I do get this working I cannot push any views from the master view to the detail. It seems as though the popOver loses its connection as a splitViewController if I pop it from a custom button I added to the view.

Is there anyway to not use a ToolBar or Navigation Bar to pop Open the master view for a splitViewController when in portrait mode that will allow me to push view in the detail view like a regular splitViewController?